# Qt.createComponent url of the library components

Tags: qt, qml, qt5

Below is a function from TimelinePresenter.qml which is a custom component I created.

```
function createMenu() {
    var menuComp = Qt.createComponent("Menu.qml");
    if( menuComp.status != Component.Ready )
    {
        if( menuComp.status == Component.Error )
            console.debug("Error: " + menuComp.errorString());
        return;
    }
}
```

It gives the error:

```
Error: qrc:/qml/timeline/Menu.qml:-1 No such file or directory
```

TimelinePresenter.qml is a resource file specified in the .qrc file and its path is qml/timeline as shown in error message so qml engine is trying to find the Menu.qml there expectedly. How can I specify the path to create qt's Menu component?

**Edit:**

my resources.qrc file

```
<RCC>
    <qresource prefix="/">
        <file>qml/main_window.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/TimelineViewItem.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/HorizontalLine.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/TimelineView.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/VerticalLine.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/timeline-item/timeline_item.h</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/TimelinePresenter.qml</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/timeline-item/analog_timeline_item.h</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/timeline-item/digital_timeline_item.h</file>
        <file>qml/timeline/timeline_presenter_backend.h</file>
        <file>qml/ControllableListPresenter.qml</file>
        <file>qml/controllable_list_backend.h</file>
        <file>qml/controllable-popup/AddControlUnitPopup.qml</file>
        <file>qml/styled/CenteredPopup.qml</file>
        <file>qml/styled/StyledTextField.qml</file>
    </qresource>
</RCC>
```

Comment: show your .qrc :)

Comment: where is `Menu.qml`?

Comment: I don't have Menu.qml. I am trying to create qt's library component Menu.

Comment: Do you mean http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-controls-menu.html or https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html?

Comment: second one with 5.7

Comment: I have the file "/usr/lib/qt/qml/QtQuick/Controls.2/Button.qml" in my filesystem but I don't know how to reference it or is there a better way than referencing absolute file urls?

Comment: From what I understand, you do not want to create the Menu.qml component, what you want is to create an object of the component https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html, I am right?

Comment: Yes I want to create an object of component  doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html

Comment: see my answer..

Comment: Why do you want to do it with JS and not declarative? (e.g. dynamically in a Loader). Creating Objects declarative is preferable for multiple reasons, not only a sometimes buggy JS garbage collector (*dtech* would tell you), but there might be reasons to do it with JS. If you'd tell us the application we might also help you to do it declarative.

Comment: @derM I have multiple rectangles on a timeline. When the user right clicks on one I dynamically create context menu based on the type of the rectangle. I add menuitems based on the type. There might be a better way but I am new to qt and don’t have much time. Those rectangles are also dynamically created so I don’t think it would be easy to do declerative menu

Comment: @AlpHancıoğlu: Shall there be the possibility to have more than one Menu open at a time?

Comment: @derM no. There is only one menu at a time.

Comment: @AlpHancıoğlu: Then you were asking for the wrong thing :D See my answer.

Comment: @derM Thanks for the answer but currently I am busy with other things so I can't try your solution right now. I will have a look at the first opportunity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are confusing the creation of a component with the creation of an object that belongs to a component.

The [Menu component](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5.11/qml-qtquick-controls2-menu.html) already exists and is provided by Qt, what you must do is create the object using the [`Qt.createQmlObject()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createQmlObject-method) method.

Example:

```
var menuObj = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 ; Menu {
MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
MenuItem { text: "Paste" } }', parentItem, "dynamicSnippet1");
```

Complete Example:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    id: parentItem

    Component.onCompleted: {
        var menu = Qt.createQmlObject('import QtQuick.Controls 2.0 ; Menu {
        MenuItem { text: "Cut" }
        MenuItem { text: "Copy" }
        MenuItem { text: "Paste" }
    }', parentItem,"dynamicSnippet1");
        // test: open menu
        menu.open()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the case you have described in your comments, I would suggest to only create one `Menu` and only `popup()` it at the place where you have clicked, setting it in a specific context.

I prepared a small example to illustrate how the `Menu` could be used:

```
import QtQuick 2.7
import QtQuick.Window 2.0
import QtQuick.Controls 2.3 // Necessary for the "Action" I used. Create the Menu otherwise if you are bound to older versions.
import QtQml 2.0

ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 600
    height: 600

    Repeater {
        model: ListModel {
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 400; y: 50  }
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 100; y: 190 }
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 70;  y: 80 }
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 30;  y: 0 }
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 340; y: 500 }
            ListElement { color: 'black'; x: 210; y: 10 }
        }
        delegate: MouseArea {
            x: model.x
            y: model.y
            width: 50
            height: 50
            property QtObject modelItem: model

            onClicked: menu.openMenu(x + mouse.x, y + mouse.y, modelItem)

            Rectangle {
                color: model.color
                anchors.fill: parent
            }
        }
    }

    Menu {
        id: menu
        Action { text: "green"    ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "blue"     ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "pink"     ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "yellow"   ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "orchid"   ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "orange"   ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "teal"     ; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }
        Action { text: "steelblue"; onTriggered: { menu.currentContext.color = text } }

        property QtObject currentContext
        function openMenu(x, y, context) {
            currentContext = context
            popup(x, y)
        }
    }
}
```

> Though I think this answer might solve your problem, I know that it is not really the answer to the question you stated initially.

---

For the Component-part: I think you misunderstood what a `Component` is - it is not an `Item`. It is a *prestage* in the creation of `QtObjects` and more something like a *prototype* or configured *factory*.

So your function - if it would work - would end at the creation of a invisible thing, from which you *could* create objects, by calling `createObject()`.

Creating `Component`s is the right thing to do, if you want to create an object at a later time and you might want to create similar objects multiple times, either by JavaScript or by other QML-types that expect `Component`s as some input (e.g. delegates).

To create Components you have multiple possibilities, e.g.:

1. `Qt.createComponent(url)`
2. `Component { SomeItem {} }`

The first expects you to know the url, which in your case, you do not. To circumvent that, the easiest solution is, to create a new File, like *MyMenu.qml*
that only contains the `Menu {}` - then you can create a `Component` from this.

The second does not expects you to know the url, but it is not dynamically created.

```
Component {
    id: myCmp
    Menu {
    }
}
onSomeSignal: myCmp.createObject({ prop1: val1 }, this)
```

Here the `Component` is automatically created when the object in the file is instantiated. This makes that (one time) initially a bit slower, since more code has to be processed, but you don't have to do it later.

Creating objects like *eyllanesc* shows with `Qt.createQmlObject("Write a new QML-File here")` might be also used to create a `Component` if the top-level element is a `Component`. If you don't have a `Component` as top-level, it will also first create a component that is once used to create a `QtObject` and then is discarded. It is the slowest but most flexible way to dynamically create objects.